# How to do nested search with custom variable in ealsticsearch using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

This is my data saved in elastic search:

```
{
  index: productName,
  type: 'users',
  body: {
    name:'xyz',
    subject:{
      12:{
        id:12,
        name:Maths
        count:3
      },
      13:{
        id:13,
        name:Physics
        count:7
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is There a way to somehow search and get total number of users whose count in maths is greater than 0. Where 12 will be in a variable say `subject_id`.
I tried searching in the docs but coudn't find any one example to use.
I am new to elastic search any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I think the best thing to do at this point is to read the [documentation on nested objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) and try to apply it on your case. It's pretty straightforward as you'll see.

Comment: @val I tried that, but the problem is that i need variable
I can do this 
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {"subject" :{
                12:{"gt" : 0}
              } 
            }
          ]
        }

But instead of 12 i need variable there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object first, like this:

```
var queryObj = {
    "query":{
      "range":{

      }
    }
  };
  queryObj.query.range['subjects.'+data.subject_id+'.opened']={
    "gte":1
  };
```

then pass this object in the body of elastic search like this

```
elasticClient.search({
    index: indexName,
    type: type,
    body: {
      queryObj
    }
  }).then(promiseFunc)
```